# How to find out the child number that "this" refers to in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

A javascript function has reference to the element that it was called from via the "this" keyword.

In my case the element is a TD

I want to know which number child element that this TD is of the parent TR

How do I do that in jQuery?

I am using version 1.7.1

For example:

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="hasBeenClicked()"></td>
  <td onclick="hasBeenClicked()"></td>
  <td onclick="hasBeenClicked()"></td>
</tr>

function hasBeenClicked()
{
  var childNumber = $(this)....
}
```

Comment: `$(this).index()`? That would tell you it's the nth child within the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  using [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> Index starts from 0

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BHLtJ/1/)</kbd>

```
$(this).index();
```

or

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BHLtJ/)</kbd>

```
$(this).index('td');
```

Comment: Got it working in the end - index is zero based - I was using it as part of an nth-child selector which is 1 based